# How to search for a single value in a column with multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, video

I've this famous dataset with data about movies and Imdb. The column 'cast' shows multiple values with names of actors and actress that are in the movie. But I want to search for a specific actor.

For example: Search for all movies with Leonardo DiCaprio in Cast. How to do that?

I'm use Pandas and Python.

I try:

```
ator = bd.loc[(bd['Cast'].str.contains('Leonardo DiCaprio'))]
```

And get: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
​

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you read the following notices, it will be better to get an answer : [mre]

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to spesify na=False so any NaN value will be considered to not contain the string

```
ator = bd.loc[bd['Cast'].str.contains('Leonardo DiCaprio', na=False)]
```

For reference and to learn more you can check: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 0):

`bd.groupby('Cast').get_group('Leonardo DiCaprio')`

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding some explanation as to how it addresses the question.